# Need help in a sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field that is a varchar that contain values such as (88,90,100,200) and i have another one contains the value 200 when using the IN clause to see if the second field in the first field it returns empty result but when comparing it with 88 it return results

So i was wondering what im doing wrong here and if there is a better way.

Here is the mysql code

```
select * from user inner join category where parent_id IN (categories)
```

- parent_id is located in the category table and the categories in the user table

Comment: where parent_id IN (categories) maybe its (category) ? Or what is categories? EDIT: nvm, just saw ur edit

Comment: Can you add the structure of the tables please?

Comment: without table structure, it's still totally ambiguous what you are really trying to join on, or even if you actually need a join at all. Structure, sample data, and desired results would make all the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a JOIN you need an ON clause to specify that you are looking for rows that somehow "match" across two tables. If you want all the rows from a single table where some column has a value that is "one of the values in this list..." you use IN. So these are both valid SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN category ON user.someColumn = category.someOtherColumn // can add WHERE clause
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE parent_id IN (88, 99, 100, 200)
```

Can't tell you exactly what query you should use unless you share your table structures, as the question is unclear.

Comment: This is an INNER join im not required to use an ON clause between the 2 tables. parent_id is INT(11) and located in the category table and categories is VARCHAR(45) in the user table and also it works in your second mysql query but the set is a variable

Comment: if the set is a variable, then substitute it in at run-time. You can do this either with simple string concatenation, or using prepare() and parameter binding (which I think is preferable).

Comment: "In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise." @http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html